# How to bind list of dynamic objects to the Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have a strongly typed view where one of the properties of the model that is passed in is a list of objects. I am handling dynamic binding of inputs to this list by using the BeginCollectionItem helper which works fine. However, I also want to initially have a group of inputs visible on the view that will bind to the 'first' object in the list.

I've tried just copying the inputs that BeginCollectionItem generates but that doesn't seem to work.

It generates inputs with name attributes like

```
invoiceItems[ef43a8f2-c6b7-4791-bf7f-6764c8e3fc9b].Description
invoiceItems[ef43a8f2-c6b7-4791-bf7f-6764c8e3fc9b].Cost
```

so I manually put 2 inputs on the view with the name attributes

```
invoiceItems[firstOne].Description 
invoiceItems[firstOne].Cost
```

but it didn't show up in the model on the controller after submitting the form.

I can't just insert one the BeginCollectionItem way when the view loads because the initial item has to be displayed differently.

Comment: Try to translate translate your dynamic input to a strongly types model-view. that will solve your problem. You may also look how to parse this data in a safe way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answer to your **question**, but I hope it will solve your **problem**.

Instead of changing the name in the view, you may try changing the model. Add a `boolean` property `IsFirst`. I believe you know in the `controller`(or wherever the model is being instantiated) which one is first. Set the first items `IsFirst` to true.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was on the right track with manually putting in the stuff that BeginCollectionItem did, I was just missing a part. You need another hidden input that tells the binding what the index you're using is.

So the following works perfectly

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoiceItems.index" autocomplete="off" value="firstOne" />
<input type="text" placeholder = "ex. Labour" id="invoiceItems_firstOne__Description" name="invoiceItems[firstOne].Description" />
<input type="text" placeholder = "ex. $15" id="invoiceItems_firstOne__Cost" name="invoiceItems[firstOne].Cost" />
```

I just added the top hidden input to what I had before and it's all good.